# how do queues provide O(1) performance on takes/puts?

Tags: data-structures, queue, time-complexity

I assume the constant time performance of takes/puts is achieved by allowing consumers and producers to access the tail/head of the queue without locking each other.  How is this achieved for in-memory queues? Does the answer change for durable queues (probably)?    How is this solved in system that imposes a limit on producers and consumers of 1 each?  How about when the system allows concurrent access?

Comment: It depends on which data structure you use for the queue. The answer for a doubly-linked list is very different to the answer for a circular array, for example. Also, if you're specifically asking about concurrent/threadsafe queues, it would help to make that clear in the question.

Comment: Updated question per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

`Queue` uses doubly linked list as it's data structure. In fact queue in Java is declared like this:

```
Queue<SomeClass> q = new LinkedList<>();
```

`LinkedList` in Java is *doubly linked list* by default.

Now `offer()` or insertion at head is always `O(1)` as you don't need to traverse the whole list and same with `poll()` where you *remove the tail* and return it.

Now as far as concurrent access is concerned it should not have any effect on the time complexity of the code.

Comment: This isn't quite right - in Java `Queue` is an interface, not a data structure, and `LinkedList` is not the only data structure implementing that interface; `ArrayDeque` is another very common one.